How to enable microphone on headset in Ubuntu 22.04?
I have a problem with the microphone. I use Ubuntu and when the headset connected with Bluetooth, I see these options:


and can't see the microphone of headset. I want to know why get the handsfree for my headset, the quality of it is very bad.
How can make ubuntu detect the microphone of the headset not handsfree?

please indicate which distro/version of Linux you are using

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

can anyone help me, please?
